# Get echo from php into javascript (separate files)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have been searching for hours and can't put this to work...

This is my first website, I have a Google gauge that need to ask a database for the value that it should put on the gauge. I know how to ask the database and how to update the gauge, the problem is how should I pass the echo variable from the php file to the javascript file. (The php code need to be in a separate file or otherwise the google gauges won't display).

You can check a actual version of the website [here](http://tecnicosolarboat.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/boatdata/) (At the moment the gauges are static).

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $DB_NAME = 'TSB';
    $DB_HOST = 'db.tecnico.ulisboa.pt';
    $DB_USER = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $DB_PASS = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $mysqli->query('USE xxxxxxxxxxx;');
    $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT SOC FROM TSB ORDER By time DESC LIMIT 1;');
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $soc = $row['SOC'];
    echo $soc;
?>
```

The output of the echo is an int, or at least came as one from the database.

What I'm trying in the javascript file:

```
function SOC() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['SOC', 0]
  ]);
  var options = {
    width: 250, height: 250,
    redFrom: 0, redTo: 10,
    yellowFrom: 10, yellowTo: 25,
    minorTicks: 5,
    majorTicks: ['0','25','50','75','100']
  };
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: '%',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('SOC'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  setInterval(function() {
    var socPHP;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'soc.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType:'text',
        // I don't know how to properly put the $soc from php in a javascript variable
    });
    data.setValue(0, 1, 100); // 100 should be replaced by the value 
    //that came from the php file and the variable should be an INT
    chart.draw( data, options);
  }, 3000);
}
```

**UPDATE After Tina Suggestion:**

```
<?php
  $DB_NAME = 'TSB';
    $DB_HOST = 'db.tecnico.ulisboa.pt';
    $DB_USER = 'xxxxx';
    $DB_PASS = 'xxxxx';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $mysqli->query('USE xxxxxx;');
    $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT SOC FROM TSB ORDER By time DESC LIMIT 1;');
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $soc = $row['SOC'];
?>;

function SOC() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['SOC', 0]
  ]);
  var options = {
    width: 250, height: 250,
    redFrom: 0, redTo: 10,
    yellowFrom: 10, yellowTo: 25,
    minorTicks: 5,
    majorTicks: ['0','25','50','75','100']
  };
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: '%',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('SOC'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  setInterval(function() {
    data.setValue(0, 1, <?php echo $soc; ?>);
    chart.draw( data, options);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: You can't use PHP in the file you want the PHP variable echo'd in? If that's the case, then you'll want to use Javascript's AJAX.

Comment: I have tried with AJAX but maybe I have not done it properly, can you please post an answer with a code example?

Comment: @bugfroggy could you please provide me an AJAX exemple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation that comes with the gauges, the data needs to be in the format: [label, value]

One way of achieving your goal is after you've sent your ajax request, you need to build an array in your php script and then use the json_encode function to output the data. You'll also need to add the parameter `dataType: 'JSON'` to your ajax request.

**EDIT: Its frustrating reading all the comments and seeing you not get anywhere so I wrote the following which you should be able to adapt.**

You need 2 files: a HTML or PHP file containing your HTML and JS, the second needs to be a PHP file containing your database query.

File 1:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "g.php",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data:{},
                success: function(x){
                  data.setValue(0, 1, x["key"]);
                  chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

File 2, g.php (This generates a random number and outputs JSON. You can put your database query here instead of the rand() function):

```
<?php

    $data = array();

    $data["key"] = rand(0,100);

    print(json_encode($data));

?>
```

The AJAX query in the first file sends a request to file 2, g.php every 2 seconds and fetches a simple JSON object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if you check https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge at javascript file line 23 they change the gauge value the way I'm trying to.

Comment: Yes, works fine on server. What output are you getting in the console?

Comment: Thank very much! I have tried to run you code separately from mine but I think that for some reason the javascript is not entering in the success: part of Ajax. I have add a console.log inside success and it doesn't output it.
Have you test your code?

Comment: Face palm. You do know that you need a webserver to run php scripts, right? lol. Got there in the end!

Comment: OH F*** I have spend all day trying to put this to work.... This was a very noob problem.. (It's my first webpage)

Comment: Since this is your first website, I suggest you take cs50x and cs75, that's how I learned. It's free, Google it or go on YouTube. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! @user2360306

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, in your javascript file just add  where it's needed, e.g.,

```
['SOC', <?php echo $soc; ?>]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that didn't work, I got this in the browser console: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Is the file a `.php` file? If not, then this error will appear. Additionally, PHP needs to be installed obviously. If you can't install PHP or change the file to be `.php` then AJAX is the way to go and I'd be happy to provide an example.

Comment: As bugfroggy indicated, you need to change your javascript file name from .js to .php .... then the php code will work within the js file.

       <script type="text/javascript" src="gauge.php"></script>

Comment: In that case how should I write the php code inside the js file that as .php extension? I tried <?php ..... ?>; but it din'd work

Comment: Yes, rename the gauge.js to gauge.php, edit your html accordingly and then edit the javascript to ['SOC', <?php echo $soc; ?>]

Comment: also php -v at Mac terminal returned PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2016 11:47:58) so php is installed.

Comment: I have rename everything and edit the html file, then I placed the content of my old php file in the beginning of the javascript but <php is giving me  Unexpected token '<' at the browser...

Comment: Hm, it should work ... can you post an example of your changes?

Comment: I have change original question and added a piece of js file after the changes...

Comment: okay but you still need to edit this

    function SOC() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Label', 'Value'],
       ['SOC', <?php echo $soc; ?>]
  ]);

Comment: I'm updating the value of the gauge in end of the code...  The problem is that the browser give Unexpected token at the very first line os the file, where the first php code starts...

Comment: It gives you this error (as far as I can tell) because it does not recognise the php code in the javascript file. At the moment I cannot tell what is exactly wrong .. your gauge.js should be a separate file and should be renamed to gauge.php and included via html in the php file that shows your gauges (the one that you provide a link to). Can you tell me what files you have and their contents each? Its a bit of a mess right now, sorry.